# Update table2 after update table1 in MySQL using Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm tryin to do a trigger with mysql to update a table2 after update a table1, basically the logic of the operation is this one:

i have a table1 which have next fields:

idtable1
   idtable2
   units

next table is like this

idtable2
   totalunits

so i need to update totalunits field of table2 with the sum of all units of table1 with same id of table2, by example:

lets say that table1 has these values:

```
idtable1 | idtable2 | units
___________________________
1        |     1    |   3
2        |     1    |   2
3        |     2    |   2
```

then my table2 should be

```
idtable2  | totalunits
________________________
1        |      5
2        |      2
```

i know maybe it's super easy but i can't find any solution, i already created a trigger but it's not working

```
 update `table2`,`table1` set totalunits= sum(table1.units) where table2.idtable2=table1.idtable2
```

Comment: Describe how it's not working. Include error messages if any.

Comment: it shows and error when i try to update table1 #1054 - Unknown column 'table1.idtable2' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query:

```
UPDATE table2 t2 SET t2.`counts` = (SELECT SUM(t1 .`units`) FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.`id2` = t2.`id2`);
```

Answer (score 0):

With a trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER upd_units AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @diff := OLD.units - NEW.units;
    UPDATE table2 SET total_units = total_units - @diff WHERE idtable2 = OLD.idtable2; 
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```